# In what order does the a basic android application execute its files?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have just started off with android studio and have made a very basic sample app with an empty activity and couple of views in it.
I have coded XML in the activity_main.xml file to create the views and coded in the ActivityMain.java to define some triggers in the button view to execute some functions.
But coming from a C/C++ background.
I have seen that the android project of mine contains several other files and have also found some other java files and also noticed that the actual file that I have worked with does not contain a main method.
So what actually is the sequence of the java file execution?
And also what is the most basic memory allotment sequence that takes place when we run the application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is main() in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293329/where-is-main-in-android) Basically the system instantiates the Activity marked as the launcher, first method called on `onCreate()`. XML is parsed when you use `setContentView` or inflate it otherwise.

Comment: Please refer to the linked duplicate question which should hopefully contain the information you are looking for. Also, what do you mean by "most basic memory allotment sequence"?